# What can be done to perform stuff when activity resumes in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities.In the start itself the first activity has suppose two edit text fields with say value (10,20)..And the first activity is calling the second activity using intent.On pressing the back button ,again first activity appears.In this case.I want to achieve that when again first activity appears(on back button).i.e resume() method is called.At that time I want to update the values of edit texts to (60,70).How should I do that.I tried it using the setText in Onresume() of the first activity,But the values are getting updated in the start itself.What can be done?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what the app does. 
But if you want to update Activity one after returning from Activity two, and Activity two is started with an Intent from Activity one, then, to start Activity 2:

use startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity. And then capture a return value in onActivityResult() in Activity one. There you can update your textView or editText.

Ref: [Getting a Result from an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: Yes ,This worked! Will you please help me with the same scenario,but now I have one main activity which has 2 intents (two buttons)  two 2,3 activity.And when I return back to the main activity after taking data from the 2,3 activity,I want to display the updated data taken from both the activities at the same time .What changes need to be done?

Comment: It is the same, read the link I left on the answer. When you call the actifity for result you pass in a number, in onActivityResult you can know from which activity your are back by checking that number. And you can take actions acordingly. Read the link. And if the answer helped you please mark it with the green tick :)

Answer (score 0):

You keep using the `Onresume()` method, but with a small change. Set up a flag to identify if it is first time.

- Declare `private boolean firstTime;` in your first activity
- Put Boolean `firstTime=true;` in your `onCreate()`
- Put `firstTime=false;` in `Onresume()`

Then in `Onresume()`,

```
if(!firstTime){
    //your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Still no change.Its giving the same result as before.Please help

Comment: Sorry there was a problem in the code i've updated. if(!firstTime) not if(firstTime){

Comment: Yes..I used if(firsttime==false) { }.. still it persists.

Comment: What exactly is the the problem now? is it works in every time including the first time or is it working only the first time?

Comment: It worked with OnActivityResult.Please could you help me with the scenario listed in the comment of answers below !